# String Array Values and HashMaps

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashmap

I've been trying to make a maze type of game by reading in from a configuration file using HashMaps to distinguish between a Room attribute vs Door Attribute. If I just print the String[] values they print the corresponding config values, however, when I try to print the values using a HashMap by calling it by its key, it tells me that the values are null. 
Any advice?

My code:

```
     while (file.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
              continue;
            }
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
            String type = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";

            String name = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";

            String wall1 = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";

            String wall2 = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";

            String wall3 = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";

            String wall4 = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";

            HashMap<String,String[]> roomSite = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
            HashMap<String,String[]> doorSite = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

            String[] options = new String[]{wall1,wall2,wall3,wall4};

            if(type.equals("room")){
                roomSite.put(name, options);
            }else if(type.equals("door")){
                doorSite.put(name, options);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error in config file. Please check that all options are valid.");
            }
            System.out.println(roomSite.get(0));
            System.out.println(doorSite.get("d0"));
  }
```

Output:

```
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
[Ljava.lang.String;@e9e54c2
null
null
```

config.ini

```
room 0 wall d0 wall wall
room 1 d0 wall d1 wall
room 2 wall wall wall d1
door d0 0 1 close
door d1 1 2 open
```

Comment: Well, do you have `0` as a key in `roomSite` or `"d0"` as a key in `doorSite` on the iterations when it prints `null`?

Comment: It might make more sense if you use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) on your line instead of all those scanners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `System.out.println(roomSite.get(0));` when it should be `System.out.println(roomSite.get("0"));`

Your maps map from `String` to `String[]`, not `Integer` to `String[]`.

Also, if you want to get a more meaningful print statement instead of `[Ljava.lang.String;@e9e54c2`, you can use the `Arrays.toString()` method.

Comment: Hi, after making the key "0", now it gives me:   [Ljava.lang.String;@e9e54c2 followed by nulls, is that normal?

Comment: You should initialize your maps before you start reading from your file. Each time you're reading in a line, you're creating a new `HashMap`. So on the first iteration when you read in room 0, you add its details to the map, which is why you see the `[Ljava.lang.String;@e9e54c2` printed. Afterwards, you're creating new maps, and adding the other rooms/doors. The "0" details aren't in the new maps, so you only see `null` printed on the subsequent iterations.

Comment: Ooooh, ok. It works now. Thanks very much for the help! I was stuck on that for like 2 hrs now :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your `HashMaps` before iterating through your file. Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String []argh) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("config.ini"));
    HashMap<String, String[]> roomSite = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String[]> doorSite = new HashMap<>();
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        String type = scan.next();
        String name = scan.next();
        String[] walls = scan.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
        switch(type){
        case "room":
            roomSite.put(name, walls);
            break;
        case "door":
            doorSite.put(name,  walls);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error in config file. Please check that all options are valid.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(roomSite.get("0")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doorSite.get("d0")));
}
```